# What to do when an imagesheet is too wide?

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk, sprite-sheet

I'm trying to develop for Android, using Lua and Corona Simulator. The maximum image size that Android accepts is 2048x2048 pixels. I currently have an imagesheet that's 148 pixels high and 4690 pixels wide. The sheet consists of 35 images on a single line. Is there a way I can break this imagesheet up in multiple lines of frames and still use the Simple animation method listed here (http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/graphics/newImageSheet.html) rather than the complex one, or do I really have to declare each frame individually?

I have tried scaling the image down to a width of 1995 pixels, and then scaling it back up inside the program, but this (obviously) resulted in terrible resolution. I also tried (although this was with another image that presented the same issue) breaking the image up into two lines, so it was twice as high and half as wide, but I couldn't get this to work with the Simple method in Corona I mentioned above. The Complex method seems like a last resort, because it's a ton of work and code declaring each frame in the imagesheet individually by x, y, width and height.

Comment: Is your image 4690 x 4690? What have you tried?

Comment: You can generate an "options" table for complex method on-the-fly.

Comment: @Schollii The image is 148 pixels high and 4690 wide. Each frame is 148 high and 134 wide. I'll update the question with what I've tried.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I'm not sure what you mean by on-the-fly. As far as I can tell, the complex method requires me to declare each frame individually, which I'd really rather not.

Comment: @Ravn - you can build you huge table in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence navigates your texture image from left to right, top to bottom. So use a 5x7 grid of sub-images (5 rows, 7 columns, instead of 1 row, 35 columns), sequenced in this manner. Your image would then be 740 x 938.

Alternately, you could have multiple image sheets and [switch between them as required](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newSprite.html).

Comment: The problem with the first solution is that the program doesn't automatically switch to the next line, and I have no idea how to make it do so. If I did what you suggest, it would throw an error upon attempting to reach frame 8.

Comment: As for the second suggestion, I had considered doing that, but I really preferred a simple solution. In any case, I absolutely loathe working with timers, so I'd probably go with the complex method if it did come to that.

Comment: There are no timers involved in either solution. Perhaps if you showed some code I could make the answer more helpful. Also, the program does automatically switch to the next line, I confirmed this before posting.

Comment: Holy crap, you're right! I must have messed up somewhere when I attempted the multiple line solution the first time! Thanks for the persistence, sir! :)